# Sitecore Forms Custom field gives 400 bad request when trying to add to a form via the forms interface

Tags: sitecore-forms, custom-field

On `Sitecore 9.2.0`, I have created a `custom field`, based on the relevant tutorial (https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/92/sitecore-experience-manager/en/walkthrough--creating-a-custom-rating-element-with-property-editor.html).

When I try to add this field into a form via the Forms UI, I see in the network tab that the relevant API call fails with a status code of 400 (bad request). All OOTB fields work fine. Sitecore logs report absolutely nothing, event viewer reports absolutely nothing.

I am obviously missing something. Any insights on where to look?

Comment: Can you turn on the Sitecore logs to DEBUG and see if it reports any error?

Comment: @AhmadZia Tried that. No data related to the action. It seems that for some reason this request doesn't register on IIS. Tried a OOTB field addition. The url structure is exactly the same (obviously, different fieldTypeId and TemplateId), so I am guessing there's something wrong in the processing itself.

Comment: for the 400 request , open chrome dev tools and check the response in Preview tab

Comment: Which browser do you use? Try Firefox or other one if you are using Chrome

Comment: To  all that provided insight, I found the root cause by decompiling the relevant DLL, I've answered my own question below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It  turns out that for the Form editor to work, all field type templates must have a standard values. By decompiling the DLL that contains the action for the API controller for the SPEAK interface of the form editor, I found that internally it runs a pipeline, and the first processor has an Assert that throws if the template for the field type does not have a (empty) standard values. Adding standard values made the error go away.

A bit more informative error than just 400 Bad Request would have been more helpful, methinks.

Comment: Many thanks. Saved my hours to go through sitecore support!

Answer (score 2):

**For anyone who is coming from Upgrade route**

I upgraded Sitecore 8.2 to 9.2 via sitecore upgrade but couldn't use form fields - note that in my case I was able to see the form items both in Forms & Content editor but couldn't edit/save them(`400-Bad request` error while adding form fields). Following steps fixed it:

1. While upgrading the `_Standard Value` of Form template items aren't created properly and essentially the Forms pipeline needs the Standard Values. Got the templates from a fresh sitecore instance to fix it. The location in content tree is `sitecore/templates/System/Forms`
2. If you have custom processors interfering `HttpRequest` pipeline `e.g. Custom MarkupProcessor`, check them out if they are stopping the Form field rendering