# Add a custom control field in Sitecore Form

Tags: sitecore-forms

"400 Bad Request" appears in the network tab when I try to add a custom control field in Sitecore Form designer.

I have already added a standard value for the template, following the instructions in this post: [Sitecore Forms Custom field gives 400 bad request when trying to add to a form](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/23437/sitecore-forms-custom-field-gives-400-bad-request-when-trying-to-add-to-a-form-v).

However, this did not resolve the issue. The custom field was working previously when I added the standard value item, so this time I created a fresh custom field and added a standard value item, but it is still not working.

I have also tried reindexing, but the problem persists. Can someone please provide assistance to clarify this issue?

Comment: One possible cause is that the field template does not have a standard value item or the standard value item is not properly configured. Another possible cause is that the field template is not created in the correct path. Additionally, there could be issues with the indexing or the configuration of the Sitecore instance. please have a double check firstly.